# Which is the best way to make web application?

Tags: javascript, php, web-applications

I'm new to web development and I want to make some small web applications like a video downloaders, an document converter, and that sort of apps. I know that I can use either a JavaScript framework (react, vue, or angular) or php (laravel) but I'm confused which one is best suited for this situation.

I don't know if the this is the right place to ask this kind of questions but I want to know your opinion, so should I go with JavaScript or go the php route? I'll appreciate you help guys and thanks.

Comment: *"I don't know if the this is the right place to ask this kind of questions"* - it's not.

Comment: where is a more appropriate exchange then @jonrsharpe?

Comment: _**primarily opinion-based** 
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: If you mean on this network, there is no suitable site. If you mean elsewhere, you'll have to find that yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a very subjective question. Personally I'd recommend NodeJS or PHP as I'm not a big fan on PHP for my own subjective reasons.

My recommendations:

- [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/): [Great ecosystem](https://www.npmjs.com/), lots of shared knowledge
- Use [Webstorm from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)
- Learn about [docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/), use it and make your deployments easy
- Use something like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) until you establish it's limitations for you then you'll be better equipped to understand why you want to host another way.

Comment: *"This is a very subjective question"* - which is why it's on hold, and you should be encouraging it by answering.

Comment: I'll follow your advice and check nodejs. Thanks Paul Carroll.